# Ожидание асинхронного ajax-запроса

Tags: ajax

Здравствуйте. Такая проблема:

```
var driver;
Driver.load(1, {
    success: function(object, operation){
        driver = object;
    }
});
console.log(driver);
```

Загружается объект Driver и я хочу присвоить его переменной. Но как я понимаю код выполняется дальше не дожидаясь ответа и driver undefined. Как решить проблему, оставив запрос асинхронным?

Comment: Наверно единственный вариант выносить дальнейший код в функцию и вызывать ее после ответа.

Comment: Не постесняюсь спросить, а что за функция .load ? где вы её откапали?

Comment: вся суть асинхронного запроса  в выполнении кода дальше без остановки на ожидание ответа, чтобы использовать данные полученные асинхронно вы должны использовать callback функцию, иначе трудно себе представить, что должно быть в console.log кроме undefined, если ответ ещё не получен.

Comment: @Димка, это из ExtJS 4, но не думал, что в этом суть.
@eicto, да я понимаю. Просто на старте системы нужно получить важные данные для ее работы и в данном случае нужно было дожидаться.

Comment: А зачем запрос в этом случае оставлять асинхронным?

Comment: @alexlz, бытует мнение, что синхронные запросы не следует применять. Если такой запрос не получит ответа, то повиснет весь браузер (в случае с хромом вкладка).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var driver;
Driver.load(1, {
    success: function(object, operation){
        driver = object;
        console.log(driver);    
    }
});
```

Comment: @inso, это гениально.